# How to list indexes on materialized views (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, indexing, materialized-views

Am I correct to think that listing indexes for materialized views is the same as listing indexes for tables? In other words:

```
select * 
  from ALL_IND_COLUMNS 
 where TABLE_OWNER='SOME_OWNER' 
   and TABLE_NAME='SOME_TABLE' 
 order by INDEX_NAME, COLUMN_POSITION;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is, yes.

When you create a materialized view, you are actually creating a table of the same name as well.  If you look at `ALL_OBJECTS`, you'll see both a table and a materialized view with the same name

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE owner = 'SOME_OWNER' 
   AND object_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation.